# Does this still give the measurable sets of an outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If we define the collection of measurable sets of a measure to be the maximal collection of sets such that $\mu(A) = \mu(A\backslash E)+\mu(A\cap E)$, where $A,E$ are a sets in the collection$-$ is this equivalent to the original definition? Certainly this contains all measurable sets in the standard definition, but perhaps there are sets that 'split some sets nicely', but fail to split other sets nicely, and perhaps we can categorize them as such.

Comment: Isn't that a circular definition?

Comment: I think I can fix it... Let's see.

Comment: Does it fix it if I just say the largest collection? Because then we're just taking measurable sets to be a collection of sets that follows Caratheodory's criterion, and then if we take the largest it's unique- right?

Comment: What do you mean by "largest"?  In any case it's not going to work.

Comment: That's a good question. Why doesn't it work? Can you give a more concrete definition?

Comment: As $\mu$ is only defined for measurable sets, and collection $S$ of sets for which $\mu(A)$ is defined for all $A\in S$ will be a subcollection of the collection of all measurable sets, no?

Comment: $\mu$ is defined for measurable sets... but isn't it just a restriction of the outer measure? So if we replace $\mu$ with $\mu^*$ my question holds.

Comment: Part of the point of the Caratheodory construction is that a measurable set can somehow be "cut however you want" (i.e. through intersection with *any* set, not just a measurable set) and the decomposition is still additive. Your notion will be weaker than that, as best I can tell.

Comment: @Ian That's what I thought, but I would really like to see a proof...